# Is there a difference between walk-in and drop-in?

Tags: word-choice

Can I refer to a *drop-in advice center* as a *walk-in advice center*? I mean is there any practical difference between these two adjectives?

Comment: Such terms are part of the adopted commercial lingo of a country and may vary from place to place.  I am not certain what an "advice center" is exactly since we don't have them here in the US, at least not under that name. Is it a fortune teller?  a medical clinic?  a psychological counseling clinic? a place to take small appliances for repair? Maybe you could tell us what you believe the term to mean, and where you've encountered one.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo There are these places where you could seek free advice on different things such as housing, financial problems or, most commonly, family issues. I saw it on an English sign outside the facility. I checked it and I noticed such a thing exists at least in the UK. I was already familiar with walk-in like a walk-in spa; then it came to me how different it could be with drop-in while in use.

Comment: It doesn't have any practical bearing on these places, but to drop in on someone and to walk in on someone have very different meanings.

Comment: In the US, *walk-in* refers to a customer who goes to a business without an appointment. I haven't heard of *drop-in* used this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have searched for the places people may visit casually for advice or assistance, both [drop-in](https://www.google.ru/search?q=drop-in+centre&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0qJb_2LbZAhUS3qQKHZXgAg4Q_AUIECgB&biw=1745&bih=872) and [walk-in](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&biw=1745&bih=872&tbm=bks&ei=CjuNWr3-IIGSkwXl8JFo&q=walk-in+centre&oq=walk-in+centre&gs_l=psy-ab.12...205939.207479.0.209786.7.7.0.0.0.0.116.696.4j3.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.ThvRAdm_5Jk) are used, the former being used [much frequently](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drop-in+centre%2Cwalk-in+center&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrop%20-%20in%20centre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalk%20-%20in%20center%3B%2Cc0).

Interestingly, but British spelling--cent*re*--multiplies the search results greatly, and  I can't help wondering why. Anyway, both seem to mean pretty much the same thing.